# Can app's download data during the installation process on iPad

Tags: iphone

So for example - while its installing it downloads a bunch of images from a server

Comment: If an app is installing how do you expect it to be run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can download at first invocation (or later, as needed), or bundle data with the app inside the `.ipa`. Downloading/installing is entirely handled by the OS, and you have no say in the process.